# Illegal argument exception: Host name may not be null

Tags: illegalargumentexception

> Illegal Argument exception: Host name may not be null

I am getting this error at last line

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(get)
```

I tried all possible solutions like encoding url if contains space etc.. and variables like name and phone all these are from my  calling class

```java
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
String time = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
String value="Dish:"+cr.getString(1)+"Quantity:"+cr.getInt(2)+"Price"+cr.getString(3).trim()+"TotalPrice:"+Integer.parseInt(cr.getString(3))*cr.getInt(2)+"Address:"+address+"CustomerName:"+name+"RestaurantName:"+cr.getString(4).trim();
url = "http:twowaits.in/orderapp.php?name="+name.trim()+"&no="+phone.trim()+"&add="+URLEncoder.encode(address, "UTF-8")+"&rest="+URLEncoder.encode(cr.getString(4),"UTF-8")+"&cost="+cr.getString(3).trim()+"&value="+URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8")+"&dishname="+cr.getString(1).trim()+"&qty="+cr.getInt(2)+"&time="+time;
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(get);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `//` after `http:`.

```
url = "http://twowaits.in/......
```

The stacktrace says it all; your URL does not contain a hostname (a domain name or IP). That means you either didn't supply one, or you made a formatting error somewhere so the URL couldn't be parsed properly. In this case, you did supply a domain name, it's just that the URL isn't formatted properly.

Note that the Apache HttpClient that you are using is deprecated and Google recommends you switch to something else, e.g. [URLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html). [Square's OKHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) is also a great alternative.

Also, you might want to try and make your code more readable. Using a builder pattern for your URI would probably help a lot. See [URIBuilder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html) or you could just use a `StringBuilder`.